# How to submit php form in C#

Tags: c#, php, http

I try to login to a website I don't want to name using C#.
On the php site there are two inputs called "httpd_username" and "httpd_password" in a form. The login button has the attribute "type=submit".

I don't know why but It's not working

I tried several code samples from many stack overflow questions.
The last I came up with was

```
  var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginpage);

  var postData = "httpd_username=" + textBox1.Text;
  postData += "&httpd_password=" + textBox2.Text;
  postData += "&form=submit";
  var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

  request.Method = "POST";
  request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  request.ContentLength = data.Length;

  using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
  {
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
  }

  var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

  var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

  MessageBox.Show(responseString);
```

But It doesn't matter if I enter the right credentials, in both cases the same html code returned from the response.

The html code of the web panel should be shown but the response returns the html code of the login html code.

Kind regards

**Edit:** It's working fine with this python code:

```
response = browser.open(url)
browser.method = "POST"

for password in wordlist:

  browser.select_form(nr=0)

  browser.form['httpd_username'] = username
  browser.form['httpd_password'] = password.strip()


  response = browser.submit()

  newUrl = response.geturl()
```

Comment: You're probably being redirected to the login page when authentication fails. It's hard to tell without knowing the site you're trying to log into and what's happening on the PHP end. If it's not a site that you manage, then you'll need to contact that website to find out if what you want to do is possible. They may have some cross-site protections preventing logging in from 3rd parties.

Comment: With python and the mechanize add-on It's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using Mechanize.NET, the .NET version of mechanize.